# Sorted edges Algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I am trying to implement the algorithm, but I am confused here to start as multiple edges have same weights,please assist

[image]

Comment: It would be great if you could tell us here about your attempts in more detail.

Comment: I have started with the edge ED as it is the least weighted, then DI

Comment: Usually when algorithm says "choose the minimal element" and there are multiple elements with minimum value, you can choose any of them (and in practice such algorithm would probably be implemented in a way that takes the edge that was first in input, or may be connecting vertices with lowest indices, or something like this).